# Does C++ have a container that stores at most one object of each type?

Tags: c++

I feel like I saw something like this before, but can't find any reference to it online.  Maybe I just don't know what to Google.

Just to be clear, I mean something providing roughly this functionality:

```
template<class... Types>
class VariantContainer {
  private:

    std::vector<std::variant<Types...>> m_values;

  public:

    template<class T>
    void add(const T &t) {
      static_assert(std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Types>...>);

      for(int i = 0; i < m_values.size(); i++) {
        if(std::holds_alternative<T>(m_values[i])) { 
          m_values[i] = t;
          return;
        }
      }

      m_values.push_back(t);
    }

    template<class T>
    T get() {
      static_assert(std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Types>...>);

      for(int i = 0; i < m_values.size(); i++) {
        if(std::holds_alternative<T>(m_values[i])) { 
          return std::get<T>(m_values[i]);
        }
      }

      throw std::runtime_error("Not found");
    }
};
```

Alternatively, it could have multiple elements of a given type and provide a way to iterate through them.

Is this just some fever dream I had or does it exist?

**EDIT**: Now that I re-read my title I can see how that sounds like a tuple, but that doesn't quite fit my use-case.

Comment: Sounds like you are tryiing to re-invent [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=std%3A%3Atuple).

Comment: If you want a run time sized container then this is what you need to do.  If you can have a compile time sized one then take a look at `std::tuple`.

Comment: what is your use-case? why cant you use tuple?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 it's a little hard to get this all into a comment, but in my use case if I were to use tuples or structs I'd be leaving nearly all of the fields uninitialized most of the time.  That said, I'm wondering if the container above fits my use case either.

Comment: you can edit your question. If you are looking for something that fits your use-case better than `std::tuple`, then what is the use-case is important information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be thinking of a `tuple`.

```
std::tuple<std::string, int, double> tuple{"Test", 15, 14.3};
auto & string = std::get<0>(tuple);
auto & i = std::get<1>(tuple);
auto & d = std::get<2>(tuple);

std::cout << string << std::endl; //Prints Test
std::cout << i << std::endl; //Prints 15
std::cout << d << std::endl; //Prints 14.3

i = 19;
std::cout << std::get<1>(tuple) << std::endl; //Prints 19

auto &[string2, i2, d2] = tuple; //C++17 feature

std::cout << i2 << std::endl; //Prints 19
std::get<1>(tuple) = 3;
std::cout << i << std::endl; //Prints 3
std::cout << i2 << std::endl; //Prints 3
```

The main limitation on `std::tuple` is that it has a fixed, compile-time determined size. If you need a flexible-sized container, the solution you're engineering is more appropriate.